# How to get postman oauth2 post request in php

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, jwt, postman

I am trying to get oauth2 request in php with laravel framework. Like **Client ID , Client Secret** . So that I can validate this data. But how can I catch this data. Here I tried

```
$request->all();
$request->get('Client_ID')
```

But it's not getting value  . **I am trying it from postman**. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried seeing what data is coming here using `dd()` ?

Comment: in $request->all() . it returns **["grant_type"=>"client_credentials","scope"=>"0"]**